# Как правильнее для поисковых систем и продвижения поступить с дублями главной страницы?

Tags: seo

Конкретно с `index.php` и `index.html`? Поставить ошибку 404 или редирект на главную 301?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте index.php и .html редирект в корень:
site.ru/index.php -> site.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас index.php и index.html являются копией `/`, то самое первое что нужно сделать - прописать [canonical url](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru).  Где то такое:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://yoursite.com/" />
```

Теперь поисковые системы будут знать о том, что эти страницы просто копии `/` и их рейтинг будет общий.

Следующий этап (сделать чуть позже) - в конфиге апача прописать редирект на главную. 301 код хороший, так как поисковые системы поймут, что теперь по старому урлу страниц нет.

Answer (score -1):

в этой ситуации самый правильный вариант 301 redirect на главную, через htaccess или в коде php прописать.
Канокал тоже можно использовать, но это костыль.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?